# Echo multiline var to Grep

Tags: bash, variables, grep

How do you pipe a multiline variable to grep and retain the newlines?

Expected results:

```
$ git status --porcelain --branch
## test-branch
M  image.go
 M item.go
?? addme.go
?? testdata/
$ git status --porcelain --branch | grep -c '^??'
2
```

"2" is the answer.

But in a script (or just entering the commands), I am not able to parse this `$x` from below.

```
$ x="$(git status --porcelain --branch)"
$ y="$(echo $x | grep -c '^??')"
$ echo "$y"
0
```

I suspect it is with how I am echoing `$(echo $x ...` within the `y` variable assignment.

EDIT: I am only executing `x="$(git status --porcelain --branch)"` one time, and parsing it a few dozen times with multiple `grep` commands for various outputs, values, counts, status, branches, behinds, aheads and other values.  Therefore I need to assign the output of `git status ...` to a variable, and parse it multiple times.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't quote `$x`, it will undergo word-splitting and `echo` will print one long line. You just need to use `"$x"`:

```
x=$(git status --porcelain --branch)
y=$(echo "$x" | grep -c '^??')
echo "$y"
```

Also, you don't have to use extra `echo`:

```
y=$(grep -c '^??' <<< "$x")
```

I recommend using [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/). It is really helpful in such cases.

Comment: I'll edit my question.  I only want to run `git status ...` one time in a variable, and parse it a few dozen times over and over for various outputs, values, counts, status, branches, behinds, aheads, etc...

Comment: @eduncan911 Oh, ok. I have update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ah, yep.  that did it!  ha, i didn't have to quote the whole thing.

Comment: @eduncan911 Exactly. When assigning to a variable, there is no word-splitting taking place.

Comment: Echo's are still warranted for multiple pipes: `$(echo "$x" | grep '^##' | grep -o '\[.\+\]$')`

Comment: @eduncan911 `$(grep '^##' <<< "$x" | grep -o '\[.\+\]$')`